# Prevent duplicate entries when saving Json with Nested Array of Objecs using Spring data Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring-data

I have a rest api that accept POST to save Candidates.

This the Object coming from POST:

```
{
"name": "renato",
"email":"rena@gmail.com",
"github":"renato.github.com",
"languages":[{"name":"Java"}],
"frameworks":[{"name":"Spring"}],
"linkedin":"renato.linkedin.com",
"motto":"the best",
"password":"1234"
}
```

then I do a Call to persist:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public boolean addCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
    if (candidateRepository.findCandidateByEmail(candidate.getEmail()) == null) {
        candidateRepository.save(candidate);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

When trying to save (automatically) the Languages and the Frameworks, I would like to check in database if there's already a entry, and if exists, update only
the correspondent relational table.

Here's the Pojos:

CANDIDATE:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "candidates")
public class Candidate {

@Id
@Column(name = "candidate_id")
@GeneratedValue
private Long cadet_Id;

@Column (name = "email")
private String email;

@Column (name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column (name = "motto")
private String motto;

@Column (name = "github")
private String github;

@Column (name = "linkedin")
private String linkedin;

@ManyToMany (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "candidate_languages",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "language_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id"))
private Set<Languages> languages;

@ManyToMany (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "candidate_frameworks",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "framework_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id"))
private Set<Frameworks> frameworks;
```

LANGUAGES

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "languages")
public class Languages {

@Id
@Column(name = "language_id")
@GeneratedValue
private Long language_Id;

@Column (name = "name")
private String name;
```

FRAMEWORKS:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Frameworks")
public class Frameworks {

@Id
@Column(name = "framework_id")
@GeneratedValue
private Long framework_Id;

@Column (name = "name", unique = true)
private String name;
```

I'm Using spring data and the default Repositorys for each class:

```
public interface FrameworkRepository extends CrudRepository<Frameworks,Long{}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: so you want to save the candidates, but only update the Languages and Frameworks if they exist?

Comment: if they exist (languages and frameworks) i only need to update the join tables